# Populate monthly table from quaterly data

Tags: ssis

I have below excel file that I am loading to ssis. The problem is that the granualrity for the date dimension is by month. Is there a way to load the data so that for Jan, Feb & Mar the value is -0.10409. April May June is 0.662643 and so on

Cheers

Aidan

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your date dimension has an Qtr Number attribute, you could join the import data to the date dimension on that field and you would create the required rows.

Comment: hi andy thanks for that. when i asked teaching assistant in college they said i would have to write sql code but i will try his.